# Конфликт js на wordpress

Tags: jquery, javascript, wordpress

Здравствуйте.

Прошу помочь с решением проблемы, есть сайт на wordpress с плагином supermenu и скачанным из Интернета скриптом генератора случайного числа.

Скрипт генератора числа постоянно конфликтует c каким-нибудь другим модулем, где есть jquery.
Сейчас меню работает, но не прилипается при прокрутке экрана.

Код js скрипта:

```
function IsNumeric(n){
    return !isNaN(n);
}

$(function(){

   $("#getit").click(function() {

        var numLow = $("#lownumber").val();
        var numHigh = $("#highnumber").val();

        var adjustedHigh = (parseFloat(numHigh) - parseFloat(numLow)) + 1;

        var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjustedHigh) + parseFloat(numLow);

        if ((IsNumeric(numLow)) && (IsNumeric(numHigh)) && (parseFloat(numLow) <= parseFloat(numHigh)) && (numLow != '') && (numHigh != '')) {
            $("#randomnumber").text(numRand);
        } else {
            $("#randomnumber").text("Укажите диапазон чисел...");
        }

        return false;
    });

    $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
        $(this).data("first-click", true);
    });

    $("input[type=text]").focus(function(){

        if ($(this).data("first-click")) {
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).data("first-click", false);
            $(this).css("color", "black");
        }

    });

});
```

И, соответственно, в шапке:

```
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.2.6");
</script>
```

Отключаю код от шапки, все работает как надо, включаю, появляются проблемы.
Надо как-то обрамить код в jqery noconflict, но не получается, помогите, пожалуйста, делаю такое впервые.

Answer (score 1):

Будь тут код ошибки, помочь было бы проще.
[Как заюзать jQuery.noConflict](http://ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=61), а так же, возможно, [это](https://codex.wordpress.org/Справочник_по_функциям/wp_enqueue_script) поможет.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function function()
Вот такая ошибка обычно появлялась в других конфликтах скрипта генератора...

Comment: Спасибо, почитала информацию по ссылкам и удалось решить проблему аж с двумя скриптами, все благодаря jQuery.noConflict.